# htaccess conditions AND statements?

Tags: .htaccess

at the end of my .htaccess i redirect all url that i consider faulty.
this works perfect but i need an exception for my own pc
for my firefox browser i want the server to react as every other request
for my chrome browsers i want full access to all files on the server
i do it this way and it works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/retpic.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pcs/.*$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^11\.11\.1\.11$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Firefox

RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/retpic.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pcs/.*$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^11\.11\.11\.11$

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

but i end up doubling the whole code... is there a more elegant solution like combining the following with an AND statement? (i found something about an OR statement but not about AND)

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^11\.11\.1\.11$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Firefox
```

edit: added more explanation on how the code works:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^11\.11\.11\.11$
```

this is from the second part it excludes my ip from this rule so i can access all files on the server, this is important since i want to be able to access my cms

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^11\.11\.1\.11$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Firefox
```

this parts includes my firefox browser when i am home so i can see if the website works with all restrictions in place. why do i have this rule: i was working on my site and restructuring some parts and it kept on working for me but when i was at a friends place i noticed it did not so i needed something to be able to check this at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nee do apply little bit of boolean algebra to combine these rules into one.

Here is you can do it for you:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=11.11.2.11 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Firefox
RewriteRule !(index\.php|retpic\.php|pcs/) index.php [L,NC]
```